# How can I make the loudness of the music playing oscillate with my timer?

Tags: java, javasound

I'm trying to make the second sound on this app. oscillate in volume based on a Sin curve as a function of time passing. How would you suggest I edit what I already have to make that work? Any help would be amazing!

I'm sorry If some of the code is bad, I stepped away from this for some time and I added some sections back in that I previously commented out. I wasn't sure if it was for a good reason or not, so I added it back in.

```
MediaPlayer beep;
MediaPlayer sound2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); //call superclass onCreate
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //inflate the GUI


    minutesChanged = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.minutesChanged);
    secondsChanged = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.secondsChanged);
    minutesTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalMinutesEntered);
    secondsTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalSecondsEntered);
    percentageFinishedAmount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.percentageFinishedAmount);
    errorMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.errorMessage);



    secondEditText =
            (EditText) findViewById(R.id.secondEditText);
    secondEditText.addTextChangedListener(secondEditTextWatcher);


    minuteEditText =
            (EditText) findViewById(R.id.minuteEditText);
    minuteEditText.addTextChangedListener(minuteEditTextWatcher);

    whichSound =
            (EditText) findViewById(R.id.whichSound);
    whichSound.addTextChangedListener(whichSoundTextWatcher);

    seekBarSeconds =
            (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarSeconds);
    seekBarSeconds.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(seekBarListener);

    seekBarMinutes =
            (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarMinutes);
    seekBarMinutes.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(seekBarListener);

    percentSeekBar =
            (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBarTotal);

    beep = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.beep);
    sound2 = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.sound);


}

private void calculate() {

    totalmili = minutesT + secondsT;



    new CountDownTimer(totalmili + 2000, interv) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            secondsEllapsed = (int) ((totalmili + 2000 - millisUntilFinished) / 1000);
            minutesEllapsed = secondsEllapsed / 60;
            secondsEllapsed = secondsEllapsed % 60;


            totalTimeEllapsed = secondsEllapsed + (minutesEllapsed * 60);
            Log.d("Lucas", "total time elapsed " + totalTimeEllapsed);


            if (totalTimeEllapsed < 10) {
                errorMessage.setText("Elapsed Time: " + minutesEllapsed + " : 0" + secondsEllapsed);
            } else if (totalTimeEllapsed >= 10) {
                errorMessage.setText("Elapsed Time: " + minutesEllapsed + " : " + secondsEllapsed);
            }

            //set seekBar minutes/seconds and changing minute/seconds textView
            seekBarMinutes.setProgress(minutesEllapsed);
            minutesChanged.setText(Integer.toString(minutesEllapsed));
            seekBarSeconds.setProgress(secondsEllapsed);
            secondsChanged.setText(Integer.toString(secondsEllapsed));

            double t = sin((360/totalmili) *(totalTimeEllapsed*1000));
            float left = (float) ((t+1.0)*0.9/2.0+0.1);
            float right = (float) ((t+1.0)*0.9/2.0+0.1);
            sound2.setVolume(left,right);
            Log.d("Lucas", "value of left and red respectively " + left + ", " +right);

            if(sound == 1){

                musicPlaying = beep.isPlaying();

                if(musicPlaying == true){

                    beep.pause();
                    beep.seekTo(0);
                    beep.start();

                } else {
                    beep.start();
                }


            }else if (sound == 2){

            if(start ==1) {
                sound2.seekTo(19);
                sound2.start();
                start = 2;


                    float left = (float) ((sin(totalTimeEllapsed)+1.0)*0.9/2.0+0.1);
                    float right = (float) ((sin(totalTimeEllapsed)+1.0)*0.9/2.0+0.1);
                    sound2.setVolume(left, right);
                   Log.d("Lucas", "value of left and red respectively " + left + ", " +right);

                musicPlaying = sound2.isPlaying();

            }else if(start ==2){

                if (totalTimeEllapsed == 11) {

                    sound2.pause();
                    sound2.seekTo(34);
                    sound2.start();




                } else if (totalTimeEllapsed == 22) {

                    sound2.pause();

                }

            }


            //calculate total percentage finished, set percentage text, set total percentage seekBar
            int percentProgress = (int) Math.round(((double) totalTimeEllapsed) / ((double) (totalmili) / 1000) * 100);
            percentageFinishedAmount.setText(percentProgress + "% ");
            percentSeekBar.setProgress(percentProgress);

            //change background and text color bassed on increasing progress
            errorMessage.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, (int) (percentProgress * 2.5), 0, 0));
            errorMessage.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, (int) (255 - (percentProgress * 2.5)), 255, 255));

        }

        public void onFinish() {
            //display on finish text
            errorMessage.setText("Done!");
        }
    }.start();


}

//listener object for the EditText's text-changed events
private final TextWatcher minuteEditTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                              int before, int count) {

        // set hours Total and converts minutes to milliseconds
        if (s.charAt(start + count - 1) == '\n') {
            minuteEditText.getText().replace(start + count - 1, start + count, " ");
            s = minuteEditText.getText();
            Log.d("Lucas", "in enter key min, s = " + s);
            try {
                minutesT = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
                minutesTotal.setText(String.valueOf(minutesT) + " Minutes");
                percentageFinishedAmount.setText(" ");
                minutesT *= 60000;

            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                minutesTotal.setText("");
                minutesT = 0;
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(
            CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }
};


// listener object for the EditText's text-changed events
private final TextWatcher secondEditTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                              int before, int count) {
        //  set minutes Total when text is changed, calls calculate, changes seconds to milliseconds
        if (s.charAt(start + count - 1) == '\n') {
            secondEditText.getText().replace(start + count - 1, start + count, " ");
            s = secondEditText.getText();
            Log.d("Lucas", "in enter key sec, s = " + s);


            try {
                secondsT = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
                secondsTotal.setText(String.valueOf(secondsT) + " Seconds");
                secondsT *= 1000;
                percentageFinishedAmount.setText(" ");
                calculate();

            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                secondsTotal.setText("");
                secondsT = 0;

            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(
            CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Yowza. I'm not really clear on what the requirements are here or what you are doing.

My approach would be radically different, and maybe missing the point of what you are attempting. It would have these elements:

1) Output via a SourceDataLine, as this gives you a handle to affect the volume of every frame.

2) Per frame, consult a pointer into a Sin LUT that has the same number of elements as needed to correspond to the desired rate. (But it could also be fine to just create an argument into a sine function that increments the correct amount each frame to get your desired rate. No need to get into a war about whether the function or the LUT performs better.)

3) Multiply the SDL frame by the Sin LUT value.

For example an LFO of 1 Hz would imply either an LUT of 44100 elements, or an argument that increments by 1/44100 per frame.

As for getting access to the individual sound frames, see the tutorial [Using Files and Format Converters/Reading Sound Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/converters.html) and look for the point in the example with the comment "Here, do something useful with the audio data that's now in the audioBytes array". That useful thing would be to convert the bytes to PCM (there are other StackOverflow explain how), get your next sin function value and multiply, then convert back to bytes.

EDIT:
Looking into the MediaPlayer API, I'm not clear you will be able to efficiently do what you want with this class.

> A player is not prepared to respond to commands quasi-immediately
>   until its status has transitioned to MediaPlayer.Status.READY, which
>   in effect generally occurs when media pre-roll completes.

Does this imply some sort of buffer-size that will limit the frequency at which you can make the volume updates? IDK. When we get into buffer-size issues that in effect enforce a maximum number of updates per second, one has to listen carefully to check that there are no clicks or zippering due to discontinuities when the volume jumps from one level to another. A lot also depends on the amount of overhead happening under the hood when you set the position for each volume change.

With a SourceDataLine output, you have clean access to each frame which pretty much eliminates the potential zippering problems. I should add disclaimer though that I haven't grappled with MediaPlayer and may be ignorant of capabilities that you can take advantage of. Regardless, SDL is low level, powerful and efficient.